# Find the norm of a bounded compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

In space $C[0,1]$ is defined bounded and compact operator $A$:
$$ Ax(t)= 2x(0) - tx(1),\enspace  t\in [0,1] $$
Find the norm of operator $A$. ($\|A\|=$ ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm of $A$ is $3$.
$$
|Ax(t)|\leq 2|x(0)|+t\,|x(1)|\leq 2\|x\|+\|x\|=3\|x\|. 
$$
So $\|A\|\leq 3$. Now let $x(t)=1-2t$. The range of $x$ is $[-1,1]$, so $\|x\|=1$. And
$$
|Ax(1)|=|2x(0)-x(1)|=2-(-1)=3. 
$$
Thus $\|A\|\geq3$, showing the equality.

Comment: With $x(t)=1-2t$, $\|Ax\|=3$, $\|x\|=1$.